# cordlell battery/charger

Tags: battery-charging

I am converting my cordless drill to corded. to do this I need to use the charger which slides on the battery to attach to the damaged tools sole plate. I made a connection between the drill motor wires and the chargers input port in order to power the motor with the original battery. I have a second identical battery charger. can I remove the charging pcb or bypass it to make a direct connection between the drill motor and the plate contacts. the charging plate will simply replace the tools damaged bottom. in this way I can use the battery as designed or charge battery as designed or a direct connection to the motor from a dc power supply. does this seem possible?

Comment: Probably not. There's no reason to think that the charger output has the current capacity to operate the motor directly -- or that its "battery charging logic" won't be thoroughly confused by having the motor as a load.

Comment: Instead, perhaps you should learn to repair the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

No, do not do this. A charger applies current in the range of tens of mA to trickle charge the battery. The motor may draw thousands of mA when its pushing a load. There are other details as to how battery charging works, but your proposal just will not work.